# .htaccess | status.php?channel=VARIABLE to VARIABLE.png

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url, url-rewriting

I made a dynamic signature script, but some forums won't show it because it the URL ends with a .php and not with a image format.

How can I make it that:
www.mydomain.com/VARIABLE.png shows the content of www.mydomain.com/status.php?channel=VARIABLE

I never worked with .htaccess before.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+hitboxstatus/status\.php\?channel=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /hitboxstatus/%1.png? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^hitboxstatus/([^/\.]+)\.png$ /hitboxstatus/status.php?channel=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Kazuto Well, your question says `www.mydomain.com/VARIABLE.png`, not `www.mydomain.com/hitboxstatus/VARIABLE.png`. Which one is it?

Comment: It is this one www.mydomain.com/hitboxstatus/VARIABLE.png. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @Kazuto then you need to add `hitboxstatus` to all the appropriate places, if the `status.php` script is in the `hitboxstatus` folder, you need to add `hitboxstatus` before it as well. see edit

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. http://5.45.101.236/hitboxstatus/Kazuto.png
.htaccess in the root folder of apache (var/www) if im not mistaken and the status.php is in var/www/hitboxstatus. Mod_Rewrite is enabled. http://5.45.101.236/index.php

Comment: @Kazuto *"if the `status.php` script is in the hitboxstatus folder, you need to add `hitboxstatus` before it as well"*, Like I said, if the status.php is in that folder, *then add the hitboxstatus in front of all instances of status.php in the rules*

Comment: There's no way for me to know, because your question very clearly states: `www.mydomain.com/status.php`.

Comment: I've c&p the code you edited and it didn't work. Also tried I the line like this "RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ hitboxstatus/+status\.php\?channel=([^&\ ]+)" same goes for the last line. Both has not worked.

Comment: Well, I forgot to put a slash in front of it and didn't know I need to move the + from +status.php to +hitboxstatus. But it still doesn't work for me. I used the code you wrote. Simple Copy&Paste. My Tree looks like this  
  
var/www/.htaccess  
var/www/hitboxstatus/status.php